# Move value to JTextField

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a random string generator:

```
public class string{
private static final String dCase = "abcdefghij";
private static Random r = new Random();
private static String pass = "";

public static void main (String[] args) {
    while (pass.length () != 1){
        int rPick = r.nextInt(4);
        if (rPick == 0){
            int spot = r.nextInt(10);
            pass += dCase.charAt(spot);
        } 
    }
    System.out.println (pass);
}
}
```

How would I get the result of what is printed here into my JTextField?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            string s = new string(); 
            textField_tf1.setText();  //This is the bit I'm unsure on
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a method in `string` class that return `pass`:

```
public class string{
private static final String dCase = "abcdefghij";
private static Random r = new Random();
private static String pass = "";

public static String randomString() { //method
    while (pass.length () != 1){
        int rPick = r.nextInt(4);
        if (rPick == 0){
            int spot = r.nextInt(10);
            pass += dCase.charAt(spot);
        } 
    }
    return pass; //return
}
}
```

And just call it in your `mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)`:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    string s = new string(); 
    textField_tf1.setText(s.randomString()); //use
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put a param (String) into setText(). In this case you could do .setText("" + spot);

*edit* the value is private so just write a retun methode and call that instead of "spot". There are plenty of ways to do that.